# comment system issue : comment disappear when refresh the page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple comment system , it's work fine , it display comments , but the problem is that when i refresh the page , all comments disappear .
this is my php code:

```
<?php
   include_once('con.php');
   if(isset($_POST['content']))
   {
      $content=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content']);
      mysqli_query($con, "insert into message (msg) values ('$content')");
   }
   $result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT msg, id FROM message WHERE seen = 1 order by id desc");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
      mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE message SET seen = 0 ");
      $msg = $row['msg'];
      ?> 
      <div class="hata"><?php echo $msg ;?></div> 
   <?php
   }
   ?>
<div class="hata"><?php echo $msg ;?></div>  <?php } ?>
```

and this is the jquery code:

```
$(function() {
   $(".submit_button").click(function() {
      var textcontent = $("#content").val();
      var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent;
      if(textcontent=='')
      {
         alert("Enter some text..");
         $("#content").focus();
      }
      else
      {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "action.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
            success: function(html){
               $("#msg_show").after(html);
               document.getElementById('content').value='';
               $("#content").focus();
            }  
         });}
      return false;
   });
});
```

as i said before the script work fine , but the only problem is when i refresh the page all comments disappear from the index page ,

Answer (score 0):

The messages are flagged seen=0. So quering "where seen=1" won't return the messages again, just new messages with flag seen=1. Using your code, every message is just queried once.
If you wan't to keep messages within your results, remove the line

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE message SET seen = 0 ");
```

Comment: when i remove that line when ever i add new comment it gives me the old ones and the old ones + the new one , i mean it gives me the old comments twice . and also when i refresh the page all comments disappear .

Comment: How often are the messages added to the database? I mean, when you simply reload the page, $_POST['content'] is still part of the request and the message is added again, so you will get it twice?

Comment: i know but i don't know the solution

Comment: You should at least do "redirect after post" which avoids adding the messages multiple times.
This plus removing the flag shows all messages once and they are not flagged "invisible" when requesting again.

Everything else needs better code / routing. Sorry.